# Avoid bash to interpret \ in a double quoted string

Tags: bash

I would like to be able to do something like this

```
VAR='\\'
echo "$VAR"
```

and get as result

```
\\
```

The result that I actually have is

```
\
```

Actually, I have a very long string with many \\ and when I print it bash removes the first \ .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: Is that on Solaris or macOS? It's rare for `bash`'s `echo` to expand backslash sequences by default. In any case, you don't want to use `echo` to output arbitrary strings as noted in the Q&A I linked to.

Comment: Do you have the `xpg_echo` shell option set in your shell? Or are you _actually_ using `-e` with `echo` (but forgot to type that in the question)?

Comment: shopt tells me xpg_echo is unset

Answer (score 2):

For `bash`'s builtin `echo` command to output a given string verbatim followed by a newline character, you need:

```
# switch from PWB/USG/XPG/SYSV-style of echo to BSD/Unix-V8-style of echo
# where -n/-e options are recognised and backslash sequences not enabled by
# default
shopt -u xpg_echo

# Use -n (skip adding a newline) with $'\n' (add a newline by hand) to make
# sure the contents of `$VAR` is not treated  as an option if it starts with -
echo -n "$VAR"$'\n'
```

Or:

```
# disable POSIX mode so options are recognised even if xpg_echo is also on:
set +o posix

# use -E to disable escape processing, and we use -n (skip adding a newline)
# with $'\n' (add a newline by hand) to make sure the contents of `$VAR` is not
# treated  as an option if it starts with -
echo -En "$VAR"$'\n'
```

Those are specific to the `bash` shell, you'd need different approaches for other shells/`echo`s, and note that some implementations won't let you output arbitrary strings.

But best here is to use `printf` instead which is the standard command for that:

```
printf '%s\n' "$VAR"
```

See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) for details.

Answer (score 0):

use 4 backslashes instead of 2

Comment: Could you explain why the user is getting only a single backslash, and why your suggestion fixes that? Take into account that a `bash` shell by default (on most systems) would _not_ output one but _two_ backslashes when running the commands that the user is showing.

Comment: The OP says that he has a very long string with many occurencies of \\ and when it is printed the first backslash is removed from each occurence, and that is the problem that he wants a solution to. so from the behavior of his bash, i can say my bash does the same and suggested that he use 4 backslashes because one backslash escapses the following one, with 2 escapes he gets 2 backslashes printed as he wants...